# NFS Share Permissions - on Debian

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, nfs

server: machine-1
client: machine-2 or any machine in the allowed-subnet.

I have created NFSv4 server on machine-1: How can I ensure that:

in the NFS folder all newly directories from machine-2 to be created with 775, and files to be created with 664 permission.

Comment: Please clarify the NFS version used, and whether you mean file/directory creation *mask* (i.e. mode bits *removed from* 666 or 777) or the resulting file/directory creation *mode*. **Directory mask** 600 or 622 makes any created directories unusable to their owner as the owner-read and owner-write bits will be masked out (= you cannot add anything to the new directory). If interpreted as **directory mode** instead, it also won't work as the owner-access bit will be missing (=you cannot access anything within the directory).

Comment: NFSv4, ok let me rephrase and make it something realistic, in the NFS folder all newly directories to be created with 775, and files to be created with 664 permission.

Comment: im thinking that I should chmod the directory to 777 and file to 666: then the default value of umask 0002 will do the work.. but I  do not know how exactly to proceed this.

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of making comments that will completely change the original question: comments are not permanent, and after the comments expire, the ultimately accepted answer to the changed question would make no sense at all to new readers seeing only the original unchanged question.

Comment: please tell me if the question makes sense now?

Answer (score 1):

First, just `chmod` the shared folder on `machine-1` to whatever you want it to be.

If all the users on any client machine (or at least those that actually write to the share) have their `umask` values set to 002, you should not - in theory - need to do anything else.

However, if you cannot be sure of the `umask` values of the client machines, you might want to add a *default ACL*  to the shared folder before creating any sub-folders. To do that, make sure the filesystem on the server `machine-1` that actually contains the shared folder has ACL support enabled, and do this:

```
setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:o::rx /shared/folder/on/machine-1
```

As a result, `getfacl /shared/folder/on/machine-1` should now return:

```
# file: /shared/folder/on/machine-1
# owner: <username of folder owner>
# group: <group name>
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

The last three lines describe the permissions automatically applied for any sub-folders and files created to this folder from this point on. Regular files will have the execute permission automatically omitted, unless the program creating the file specifically indicates it wants to create an executable file.

Comment: So according to my need, I should chmod 775 to "/shared/folder/on/machine-1", and then apply the acl: 'setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:o::rx /shared/folder/on/machine-1' so this will just cater the directories to set to 775, what about the newly created files which needs to have permissions of 664 in the NFS shared folder.

Comment: "Regular files will have the execute permission automatically omitted, unless the program creating the file specifically indicates it wants to create an executable file." Basically, the default permissions set works sort of like an `umask`, although it is expressed very differently.

Comment: so to me, I think this could be achieved via taking the directory mode for newly file to 777 , and file mode to 666 then, the default umask value is set 0002 on machine-1 (not considering the umask of other machines in the network), that would do the work.. 0666-0002= 664 & 0777-0002=775. But the problem is I do not know how to set dir-> 777 & file->666 on NFS directory because as I am changing the mode: the mount on the network machine fails with the "permission Denied"

Comment: When a new file or directory is created to a NFS filesystem on machine-2, the umask on machine-1 is not consulted at all. If you cannot `chmod` something, *you are not its owner*. If the default `root_squash` NFS export option is in effect, it makes the root of the NFS client be equivalent to `nobody` on the NFS-mounted filesystem. So if the directory is owned by root, *you must actually log on `machine-1` and become root there* to make the change. On a NFS-mounted filesystem, a regular user with proper group membership can easily be more powerful than the root user of the NFS client system.

Comment: You are right, i shared the NFS with the root_squash option ON. and before sharing i ->  chown nobody:nogroup "/shared/folder/on/machine-1" to meet the requirement of my task. Does it mean unless i do no_root_squash: my config won't work?